# Is this foldRight for this Streams implementation lazy or strict

Tags: scala, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation, fold

I am reading *Functional Programming in Scala* and am on chapter 5, which covers strictness and laziness. I've done all the problems in the book up to 5.13.

One thing I realized as I was working through the problems was that I didn't really understand all the nuances of foldRight until I started doing the problems in this chapter. My question is about the implementation of foldRight given in this chapter.

Let's begin by looking at the implementation for Streams given in this chapter.

```
import Stream._
trait Stream[+A] {

  def toList: List[A] = this match {
    case Empty => Nil
    case Cons(h, t) => h() :: t().toList
  }

  def foldRight[B](z: => B)(f: (A, => B) => B): B = // The arrow `=>` in front of the argument type `B` means that the function `f` takes its second argument by name and may choose not to evaluate it.
    this match {
      case Cons(h,t) => f(h(), t().foldRight(z)(f)) // If `f` doesn't evaluate its second argument, the recursion never occurs.
      case _ => z
    }

  def map[B](f: A => B): Stream[B] =
    foldRight(empty[B])((h,t) => cons(f(h), t))

  def filter(f: A => Boolean): Stream[A] =
    foldRight(empty[A])((h,t) =>
      if (f(h)) cons(h, t)
      else t)
}

case object Empty extends Stream[Nothing]
case class Cons[+A](h: () => A, t: () => Stream[A]) extends Stream[A]

object Stream {
  def cons[A](hd: => A, tl: => Stream[A]): Stream[A] = {
    lazy val head = hd
    lazy val tail = tl
    Cons(() => head, () => tail)
  }

  def empty[A]: Stream[A] = Empty

  def apply[A](as: A*): Stream[A] =
    if (as.isEmpty) empty
    else cons(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))
}
```

In particular, let's zoom in on the definition of foldRight given here:

```
  def foldRight[B](z: => B)(f: (A, => B) => B): B = // The arrow `=>` in front of the argument type `B` means that the function `f` takes its second argument by name and may choose not to evaluate it.
    this match {
      case Cons(h,t) => f(h(), t().foldRight(z)(f)) // If `f` doesn't evaluate its second argument, the recursion never occurs.
      case _ => z
    }
```

From the text in the book, we know that this implementation of foldRight will not evaluate the second argument of the "chain" function unless it is called. Therefore, foldRight can terminate early before evaluating all the elements of the Stream. Consider this implementation of takeWhile in terms of foldRight as an example:

```
  def takeWhile(f: A => Boolean): Stream[A] =
    foldRight(empty[A])((h,t) =>
      if (f(h)) cons(h,t)
      else      empty)
```

This call to foldRight in the definition of takeWhile can terminate early before traversing all the elements of the Stream. So we know foldRight can terminate early. However, this is not the same thing as saying foldRight is lazy. My question is if this implementation of foldRight is itself lazy or strict. That is, does it apply `f` to every relevant element in the Stream?

For example, let us take this example:

```
val someStream = Stream.apply(0, 1, 2, 3, 5)
someStream.foldRight(Empty:Stream[Int]){ (e, acc) =>
  Cons(()=>e, ()=>acc)
}
```

What this call to foldRight would normally do for a non-lazy collection such as a list is that it will copy the list. For this call to `someStream`, however, will it create a copy of all the members of the Stream? Or will it only evaluate the first term?

Recall that the function in foldRight has the following signature: `(A, => B) => B`. My question really boils down to when `acc`, the call-by-name second argument of type `B`, is evaluated. Is it evaluated when `f` is first called? Or is `acc` evaluated when `()=>acc` is evaluated? Depending on which one it is, we will either evaluate all the members of the Stream or only the first one when we perform the fold.

And just to reiterate, saying that foldRight terminates early and saying that foldRight is lazy are two different things. The discussion in the book makes it clear that the first statement can be true. This foldRight can terminate early without traversing all the elements of the Stream. But is the second statement true? Is the foldRight we have here lazy?

I bring this up because there is a program trace on page 72 that I don't think I fully understand. It is linked to whether foldRight is itself lazy or not.

```
Stream(1,2,3,4).map(_ + 10).filter(_ % 2 == 0).toList
cons(11, Stream(2,3,4).map(_ + 10)).filter(_ % 2 == 0).toList
Stream(2,3,4).map(_ + 10).filter(_ % 2 == 0).toList
cons(12, Stream(3,4).map(_ + 10)).filter(_ % 2 == 0).toList
12 :: Stream(3,4).map(_ + 10).filter(_ % 2 == 0).toList
12 :: cons(13, Stream(4).map(_ + 10)).filter(_ % 2 == 0).toList
12 :: Stream(4).map(_ + 10).filter(_ % 2 == 0).toList
12 :: cons(14, Stream().map(_ + 10)).filter(_ % 2 == 0).toList
12 :: 14 :: Stream().map(_ + 10).filter(_ % 2 == 0).toList
12 :: 14 :: List()
```

Notice how in this trace, the first term (the 1) is passed through the map and filter once before any of the subsequent terms are. Since the map and filter are defined in the Stream using foldRight, this has implications for my question.

So, let's summarize my question:

1) Is foldRight in the implementation given lazy or strict? This is a different question from whether it terminates early.

2) For the following example code,

```
val someStream = Stream.apply(0, 1, 2, 3, 5)
someStream.foldRight(Empty:Stream[Int]){ (e, acc) =>
  Cons(()=>e, ()=>acc)
}
```

When is `acc`, the call-by-name parameter, evaluated? Is it when `f` is called and `(e, acc) => Cons(()=>e, ()=>acc)` is first created? Or is it when `()=>acc` is evaluated?

3) Please explain why in the program trace given, the first term is passed through the map and filter first before moving onto the second term.

You are encouraged to use the text of *Functional Programming in Scala* to make your point.